# Windows SNMP Traps

Tags: windows, central-processing-unit, snmp, cpu-usage, windows-event-log

I test SNMP Traps on Windows 10 and Windows 7.
Windows 7 has Traps Sender and Windows 10 has Traps Reciever.

1. Enabled SNMP On Windows 10 & 7.
2. Enabled Traps On Windows 7.
3. Installed a *Traps Reciever* On Windows 10.
4. Configured *Event to Trap Translator* (evntwin.exe) for LogOn-LogOff Users On Windows 7.
   [image]
5. After LogOn on Windows 7, a trap has send to Windows 10.
   [image]

After passing the Steps, I want to get *CPU Usage, Percent and Temperature* Traps from Windows 7 to Windows 10. What do I do to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the setup you have, you only have the ability to send existing Windows events to your SNMP Trap Receiver. Windows doesn't generate events when the CPU usage exceeds a certain threshold, or when the temperature of a component in your hardware exceeds a preset temperature.

You have to install 3rd party software like [EventSentry (Light)](http://www.eventsentry.com) to do this. Some 3rd party software (like EventSentry) may also have the ability to natively send SNMP traps so that setting up additional software to send SNMP traps is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Traps are the notification about the situation. It is necessary to set thresholds, then they will be sent.

Comment: You'd need software first to set the thresholds in; Windows doesn't natively have the ability to generate traps.  In the OPs description, he only mentions setting up software to generate SNMP traps when certain Windows Events happen; he'd need other software to generate traps on performance counters.